# Passing any object type to a function C++

Tags: c++, boost

I am using a library that provides different types of Signal Objects.
The library has a method:

```
void sendSignal(boost::shared_ptr<ISignal>)
```

Each Signal object provided by the library implements the ISignal interface. The ISignal interface does not provide any cloning methods. However, all the objects that implement ISignal do have a copy constructor.

I want to create a function that takes any type that implements ISignal, clones that object by calling the copy constructor, and returns the new copied object. I want to call sendSignal multiple times on different copied objects.

The code currently calls the copy constructor of the different objects in multiple locations. I was hoping there is a simple way of perhaps passing template to a function and have that function copy that object for me, by assuming that the object has a copy constructor.
However, my problem is I can't pass ISignal because that doesn't specify any copy constructor, and I can't pass a specific object that implements ISignal .
Is there any way I can do this, without C++11?

Comment: The function you want to write -- where you call it, do you know the subtype of `ISignal` you are going to send, or not?

Comment: Yes, but I can always cast it to ISignal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class XSignal,
  class=typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<ISignal,XSignal>::value
  >::type
>
std::shared_ptr<XSignal> CopySignal( XSignal const& signal ) {
  return std::make_shared<XSignal>(signal);
}
```

is a function that can accept an instance of any class derived from `ISignal` and produces a shared pointer copy.

You have to know the actual derived type at compile time to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

A copy constructor of a base class has no means of copying the entire derived object that the base class is a part of. This goes for C++ or C++11. This is fundamental to C++.

The base class must define a virtual clone() method, or something of similar name, and each derived class must override clone() to construct another instance of the derived class on the heap, then return a pointer to it. That is the only portable way to do this in C++.

If the base class has at least one virtual method, you might be able to get away with writing an external implementation of clone() that tries a `dynamic_cast` to each possible derived class of the base class, and, if it succeeds, implements a derived class-specific object copy.

Comment: hmm, instead of a function that tries to dynamic cast. Is there a way I can pass the type to the function?

Comment: This is called a "template". Define a function template. Pass the type as the template parameter. Of course, you have to know the type. If all you have is some other object, the only way to determine its derived type is via dynamic_cast, presuming that there's at least one virtual method in the class.